# backward shift operator as a sum (heuristic solusion)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I am interested in converting $(1-L)^nX_i$ to a sum, where $L$ is backward shift operator.

Let give you an example,
\begin{align}
  \triangle^1  &=X_{i+1}-X_{i}\\
 \triangle^2 & =X_{i+2}-2X_{i+1}+X_i\\
 \triangle^3 & =X_{i+3}-3X_{i+2}+3X_{i+1}-X_{i}\\
 \triangle^n &=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{j}(-1)^iX_{i+j}
\end{align}
they can be written like

\begin{align}
\triangle^1 %&=X_{i+1}-X_{i}\\
&=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{1}X_{i+j}-2X_{i}\\
\triangle^2 %&=X_{i+2}-2X_{i+1}+X_i\\
&=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2}X_{i+j}-3X_{i+1}\\
\triangle^3 %& =X_{i+3}-3X_{i+2}+3X_{i+1}-X_{i}\\
& = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{3}X_{i+j} -4\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2}X_{j+i}+2\sum\limits_{j=0}^{1}X_{i+j}+4X_{i+1}\\
\end{align}

so is there any way of writing $\triangle^n$ as simple sums like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
Y_{i;k}=\sum_{j=0}^kX_{i+j}
$$
Then $X_{i+k}=Y_{i,k}-Y_{i,k-1}=(△^1Y_{i})_{k-1}$, so that all that has been achieved is one-up the power of the difference operator.
\begin{align}
(△^1X)_{i}=(△^2Y_{i})_{-1}&=Y_{i,1}-2Y_{i,0}+0,\\
(△^2X)_{i}=(△^3Y_{i})_{-1}&=Y_{i,2}-3Y_{i,1}+3Y_{i,0}-0,\\
(△^3X)_{i}=(△^4Y_{i})_{-1}&=Y_{i,3}-4Y_{i,2}+6Y_{i,1}-4Y_{i,0}+0,\\
\end{align}
where $Y_{i,-1}=0$ is the empty sum.

Comment: That is an amazing answer. Thanks a lot.